# Could not initialize NNPACK

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to run a model for generating art images.
In Jupyter notebook ( on vs code )  the script run correctly but when I'm trying to run the same code on the .py file it gives this error :

[W NNPACK.cpp:80] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware.

Answer (score 0):

`unsupported hardware` for nnpack typically happens if youre running on `x86 cpu` , but missing some common extended cpu instructions (either a old cpu or you're running inside a virtual machine that doesn't do full emulation properly - e.g., virtuabox is known for that).

I found solution here to disable nnpack , but it isnt working for my torch version(2.1.0).
https://python-code.dev/articles/411733062
You can disable NNpack manualy

> ```
> import torch
>
> torch.backends.nnpack.enabled = False
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Try reinstalling easyocr (if you are using it), from the official easyocr github repository

This worked for me:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/jaidedai/easyocr.git
```

"The message will probably still appear, but this will no longer prevent the program from running completely"

Comment: Firstly, the error says it's a hardware problem. How is EasyOCR going to fix that? Secondly, the simpler way to install EasyOCR is `pip install easyocr`.